# Access count returned by a query

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
Connection con = ConnectionProvider.getCon();
Statement s_sickLeave = con.createStatement("select count(leavetypeid) from leave where leavetypeid=2");
ResultSet rs_sickLeave = s_sickLeave.executeQuery();
Integer sick_leave_count = rs_sickLeave.getInt(1);//line 4
```

I'm getting an exception at line 4. How do I access the count value returned by the query?

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through the result set to read each of the row.

**Change**:

```
ResultSet rs_sickLeave = s_sickLeave.executeQuery();
Integer sick_leave_count = rs_sickLeave.getInt(1);//line 4
```

**To**:

```
ResultSet rs_sickLeave = s_sickLeave.executeQuery();
if ( rs_sickLeave.next() ) {
    Integer sick_leave_count = rs_sickLeave.getInt(1);//line 4
}
```

As `count(x)` returns a single row, you can iterate only for a single row. Otherwise use `while(rs.next())` looping syntax.

**Refer to**:

[ResultSet.next()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#next%28%29)
*Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. A ResultSet cursor is initially positioned before the first row; the first call to the method next makes the first row the current row; the second call makes the second row the current row, and so on.*